# PHP file_exists() for URL/robots.txt returns false

Tags: php, robots.txt

I tryed to use file_exists(URL/robots.txt) to see if the file exists on randomly chosen websites and i get a false response;

How do i check if the robots.txt file exists ?

I dont want to start the download before i check.

Using fopen() will do the trick ? because : Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

and i guess that i can put something like:

```
$f=@fopen($url,"r"); 
if($f) ...
```

my code:

http://www1.macys.com/robots.txt
maybe it's not there
http://www.intend.ro/robots.txt
maybe it's not there
http://www.emag.ro/robots.txt
maybe it's not there
http://www1.bloomingdales.com/robots.txt
maybe it's not there

```
try {
            if (file_exists($file)) 
                {
                echo 'exists'.PHP_EOL;
                $curl_tool = new CurlTool();
                $content = $curl_tool->fetchContent($file);
                //if the file exists on local disk, delete it
                if (file_exists(CRAWLER_FILES . 'robots_' . $website_id . '.txt'))
                    unlink(CRAWLER_FILES . 'robots_' . $website . '.txt');
                echo CRAWLER_FILES . 'robots_' . $website_id . '.txt', $content . PHP_EOL;
                file_put_contents(CRAWLER_FILES . 'robots_' . $website_id . '.txt', $content);
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'maybe it\'s not there'.PHP_EOL;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'EXCEPTION ' . $e . PHP_EOL;
        }
```

Comment: I think you're gonna have to check the response header and see if it contains a 404 not found error.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Please ensure you have error reporting and display errors turned on: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: fopen with r flag will do the trick

Comment: @Edwin Drood i would love to do that, i dont know how

Comment: @DaveRandom 10x for the advice

Comment: @Kamil done that, it works ... but not for all websites, i think i need to send headers with cURL

Comment: @edwin, now i know :)) http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-check-if-file-exists-on-different-domain/

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian If all you wan't to do is check whether the file exists, you should send a `HEAD` request and examine the response code, which you can indeed do with curl

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian Good for you bro. :)

Comment: i want to do the crawler in the right way, i dont want it to abuse of any website rules; thanks for the tips guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file_exists` cannot be used on resources on another websites. It's intended for local filesystem. Have a look [here](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-check-if-file-exists-on-different-domain/) on how to perform the check properly.

As other have mentioned in the comments and as the link says it's (probably) easiest to use `get_headers` function to do this:

```
try {
    if (strpos(get_headers($url,1),"404")!==FALSE){
        ... your code ...
    } else {
        ... you get the idea ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaveRandom: That I did not know :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not yet I'm afraid, look at `),1)`

Comment: @DaveRandom: Attempt #2... Coffee break methinks :)

Answer (score 4):

Just to second what other people said,

it's best to use cURL in php to find out if that http://example.com/robots.txt returns a 404 status code. If it does, then the file does not exist. If it returns a 200 it means it exists.

Be wary of custom 404 pages though, I'm never looked to find out what they return.

Comment: @EdwinDrood Not necessarily. There are many, many site admins who understand worryingly little about HTTP and may return an error page with a 200 response code, I've also seen sites that 3xx redirect you to error pages. Both of these are massive protocol violations, but some people seem to think that RFCs don't apply to them.

Comment: a link would be usefull for this, using cURL

Answer (score 2):

[The `http://` wrapper does not support `stat()` functionality](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), which [`file_exists()` needs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php); you will need to check the HTTP response code from e.g. cURL.

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

Comment: Is it really that stupid that it won't treat a 200 as "this file exists"?

Comment: @DaveRandom: It's PHP. I've stopped wondering if it's "really that stupid" a *LONG* time ago.