# PHP if file exists

Tags: php

Here is my code.

```
$filename = "$myMedia catalog/category/ $myImage.png";
$filename = str_replace(" ", "", $filename);

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

The `variable` above outputs `http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/media/catalog/category/Game_Used.png` which does exist. However, it says that it does not exists.

Any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP file\_exists() for URL/robots.txt returns false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966187/php-file-exists-for-url-robots-txt-returns-false)

Comment: Sorry. I did a search but couldn't find what was wrong :(

Comment: Why are you putting spaces in `$filename` if you're just going to remove them on the next line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to check if image file exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try to use like this:

```
 $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . "/ $myMedia catalog/category/ $myImage.png";
 $filename = str_replace(" ", "", $filename);

 if (file_exists($filename)) {
     echo "The file $filename exists";
 } else {
     echo "The file $filename does not exist";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Yah I just needed to remove the http:// and only include the directory url. Thank you! Will accept in 7 minutes :) +Vote

Answer (score 4):

I don't know, but I think, the following code will be more successful if you have external web items as assets:

```
$filename = $myMedia."catalog/category/".$myImage.".png";
$headers = @get_headers($filename);
$exists = ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

Answer (score 2):

OT: Instead of using spaces and str_replace(" ", "", $filename) you can surround variable betwen "{}" brackets.

`$filename = "{$myMedia}catalog/category/{$myImage}.png";`

Answer (score 0):

That file looks like it is outside of your web root. As a result it is not available via the web. If you're trying to check a file that is local on your machine, use the file root instead. (i.e. /path/to/media/catalog/category/Game_Used.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the path to the file or the directory you cannot use `http://` links

[file_exists documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) it states that the file_exists() function is only available with some URL wrappers as of PHP 5.0.